# Database Link - Invalid username/password

Tags: sql, oracle12c

I have two databases on my computer: orcl and orcl1.

From orcl1, I have created the following database link:

```
create public database link remote_connect
connect to system identified by ***
using 'orcl';
```

I then run the following query:

```
SQL> select * from test@remote_connect;
select * from test@remote_connect
                   *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
ORA-02063: preceding line from REMOTE_CONNECT
```

I have ensured that the username and password are correct as I used them to login to orcl. What is the problem and what can I do to fix it?

EDIT:

My tnsnames.ora file looks like this in the orcl1 directory:

```
ORCL1 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1522))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl1)
    )
  )

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1522))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl1)
    )
  )
```

And my tnsnames.ora file looks like this under the orcl directory:

```
ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )

ORCL1 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
```

Comment: Are you sure it's the *same* `orcl` you connect to? That TNS alias will be resolved by the DB server's `tnsnames.ora`, not the client version you might have used (if they are different installations).

Comment: Right, but... according to that, while you're on `orcl1`, referring to the `orcl` alias is actually still pointing to the `orcl1` service/instance.

Comment: What should I do to fix the issue that you are pointing out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find it simpler to use easy connect syntax rather than using TNS aliases, as it seems like using those is making it unclear which database you are actually connecting to.

You can do something like:

```
create public database link remote_connect
connect to system identified by ***
using '//localhost:1521/orcl';
```

Comment: It works! Is there any reason why what I put above doesn't work?

Comment: Nevermind. I fixed the information in my tnsnames.ora file. The correct service names and port numbers are now listed and the issue is resolved! Thanks!